# Images are too stretched in html/css

Tags: html, css

My background images are all too stretched width wise and I have tried countless things to try and make it work. I have changed width parameters, height parameter, looked on different sights for answers, and could not find anything that worked. The pictures are background images and are in an animation to fade through the images. I am using Google Chrome as the browser and pictures that I have on my desktop. I found some pictures online to add in the snippet.

```css
#crossfade > img {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
}

#crossfade > img:nth-child(2)  {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div id= 'crossfade'>
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg">
   </div>




</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Remove either `width:100%` or `height:100%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to image aspect ratio. Instead of adding img element add a div element with a background-image. you can then play with the height, position accordingly. It will keep your aspect ration intact. Please see the below solution or run it in codepen https://codepen.io/salinaacharya/pen/PVowPz

```
    <html>
  <div id= 'crossfade'>
   <div class="image-box" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg)">
    </div> 
    <div class="image-box" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg)">
    </div>
    <div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg)">
    </div>
    <div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg)">
   </div>
  </div>
</html>

#crossfade > .image-box {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
}

#crossfade > .image-box:nth-child(2)  {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
#crossfade > .image-box:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
#crossfade > .image-box:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
#crossfade > .image-box:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Comment: i tried this and tweaked it a little and it worked. Such an easy fix i don't know how I didn't think about it sooner. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the property `width` or `height` from your `#crossfade` element in order the have a correct scaling, you can set `min-width` and `min-height` in order to achieve the full screen mode that you're looking for, although you might lose some of the image visibility.

```
#crossfade > img {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to the image

```css
#crossfade>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
}

#crossfade>img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

#crossfade>img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

#crossfade>img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

#crossfade>img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 24s;
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='crossfade'>
  <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg">
</div>
```